# Using Google Cloud Secret Manager with Cloud Functions for Firebase vs Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

`Google Cloud Secret Manager` provides a simple and quick way to have access to its secrets with `Cloud Functions for Firebase`. Basically, you just set some secrets using its intuitive CLI (e.g. `firebase functions:secrets:set SECRET_NAME`), add a parameter called `runWith` (e.g. `.runWith({ secrets: ["SECRET_NAME"] })` in your source code, and voila. This works even great when testing functions locally!

On the other hand, using SM on `Cloud Run` requires more steps like setting up services accounts, dependencies, and environment variables ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs)). Although using the `Google Console` to configure secrets, there're still more steps involved.

As an example, here is what a node.js code for `Cloud Run` would look like ([ref](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/serverless-expeditions/blob/f0bbb8e4d380033b00f7b4a89212a9f068c588e0/secret-manager/secret-manager-client-lib/index.js#L65)):

```
const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

async function accessSecret(name, version='latest') {
  try {
    if (!process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID) {
      throw 'Please set the GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID environment variable.';
    }
    const fullName = `projects/${process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}/secrets/` +
                     `${name}/versions/${version}`;
    const [response] = await client.accessSecretVersion({name: fullName});
    const payload = response.payload.data.toString();
    return payload;
  }
  catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.toString());
  }
}
```

Is there a better and convenient way to use SM on a code for a Cloud Run project? Also wondering what is the performance impact of the two different approaches on both products.

Comment: Please show what you are currently implementing in code. We can then make suggestions to improve your code. Otherwise, your question is off-topic.

Comment: Code example added with additional question regarding performance impact.

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that there are no other ways to use `Secrete manager` on `cloud run` other than following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#use_secrets_in_your_code)

[`Cloud Functions for Firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/functions-and-firebase) has extended  behavior of Firebase and integrated Firebase features. The simpler steps you mentioned to [integrate secrets with cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#create-secret) for firebase might be the feature added by the firebase.

And you can see that [`Cloud Functions for gcp`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets#gcloud) somehow follows similar steps as `cloud run` on gcp.

`Cloud run` is not supported on `Firebase`. Hence, it doesn't have extended features like `Cloud Functions for firebase`.